# function with readystatechange not firing

Tags: javascript

I've got the following function that should print 'done' after an xhr request has completed.

The xhr request is initiated when a user drops an image into a wysiwyg editor and it is automatically uploaded.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

        function newXHR() {
            var realXHR = new oldXHR();
            realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                if(realXHR.readyState==4 && realXHR.status==200){
                    afterAjaxComplete() //run your code here

                    console.log('done');

                }
            }, false);
            return realXHR;
        }
        window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;

    });

</script>
```

Any thoughts as to why it's not firing?

Thanks!

Comment: can we assume you have jQuery on the page since you have `$(document).ready(function(){` which uses it?

Comment: Yes, I do have jquery running on my page. Thanks for confirming

Comment: perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do since `var myxhr window.XMLHttpRequest();` is a constructor and then you would typically do `myxhr.onreadystatechange = function () {`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: How do you invoke the `window.XMLHttpRequest` after you reset it ? Because you cannot probably call `new` again on the instance you already created in the `newXHR` again. This creates inconsistency in the existing `window.XMLHttpRequest` that might break some third party code, presumably from jQuery. Do your subsequent XHR request fire ?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure the desire here but this function should return an XHR object.

I also added a second example (with reference to source) which also includes a `readyStateChange` which might fire more often than desired for use - see the other event handlers for possible insight.  Note: examples do not actually "run" here due to CORS blocking.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function newXHR() {
    const realXHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        afterAjaxComplete(); //run your code here
        console.log('done');
      }
    }, false);
    return realXHR;
  }
  var myxhr = newXHR();

});
// borrowed from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/loadend_event

const xhrButtonSuccess = document.querySelector('.xhr.success');
const xhrButtonError = document.querySelector('.xhr.error');
const xhrButtonAbort = document.querySelector('.xhr.abort');
const log = document.querySelector('.event-log');
const readylog = document.querySelector('.readyevent-log');

function handleEvent(e) {
  log.textContent = log.textContent + `${e.type}: ${e.loaded} bytes transferred\n`;
}

function handleReadyEvent(e) {
  readylog.textContent = readylog.textContent + `${e.type}: state: ${this.readyState }  status: ${this.status} r: ${this.response}\n`;
}

function addListeners(xhr) {
  xhr.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('loadend', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('progress', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('error', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('abort', handleEvent);
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', handleReadyEvent);
}

function runXHR(url) {
  log.textContent = '';

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  addListeners(xhr);
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}

xhrButtonSuccess.addEventListener('click', () => {
  runXHR('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/16553/DgsZYJNXcAIPwzy.jpg');
});

xhrButtonError.addEventListener('click', () => {
  runXHR('https://somewhere.org/i-dont-exist');
});

xhrButtonAbort.addEventListener('click', () => {
  runXHR('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/16553/DgsZYJNXcAIPwzy.jpg')
    .abort();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <input class="xhr success" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (success)" />
  <input class="xhr error" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (error)" />
  <input class="xhr abort" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (abort)" />
</div>

<textarea readonly class="event-log"></textarea>
<textarea readonly class="readyevent-log"></textarea>
```

totally untested code for jQuery ajax example ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#formbutton').on('click', function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#uploadfile')[0].files[0]);

    var jxhr = $.ajax({
      url: 'savemyfileUrl',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
      contentType: false // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }).always(function(dataOrjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHROrErrorThrown) {
      console.log("always" + textStatus);
    });

    jxhr.always(function(data) {
        console.log("another always");
      })
      .then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("It is done" + textStatus);
      }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("It failed" + textStatus);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  Something: <input type="text" value="example text">
  <button id="formbutton">GO</button>

</form>
File?: <input id="uploadfile" type="file">
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response mark. I've added this code to my website and, upon a xhr request being created when a file is uploading, the function doesn't seem to fire. I'll be honest. I have no clue what much of this code is doing, so I'm not even sure where to start debugging. I've been fighting with this problem for awhile. I don't want to waste anymore of your time, so I think I may have to pay someone on upwork to help me with this. I do appreciate your response though.

Comment: key point here is that the event you have, fires multiple times during a request.

It MIGHT be easier, since you have jQuery just to use the `.ajax()` from that library for you to make this easier for you to understand/manage.  If you upload the document using ajax (alias for XHR) you can chain it to another request if needed...like I indicated depends on your desire

Comment: added a jQuery example of totally untested code to show form of that (probably more complex than needed)

Comment: Thanks mark. The issue is that all of the code supporting this file load functionality is built into a package that I'm using (django-summernote). I've i was writing the ajax calls myself, I'd certainly integrate another solution like yours. I think I'll need to make use of something similar to the solution that you posted initially. Thanks so much for your response!

Comment: yes, perhaps `readystatechange` is the wrong event to listen for in that case